# Enviar input para salvar no arquivo JSON

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django

Tenho uma tela onde existe um auto-complete para itens de venda, o usuário pesquisa o item por nome ou código, até aqui tudo funciona.

Preciso captar o item escolhido e enviar para o *backend* (Django) para poder salvar em um arquivo JSON. A ideia é ter um JSON para cada conta.

Mas não sei como enviar os `inputs` para o *backend* de modo que possa gravar isso em um arquivo, já que vou carregar esse mesmo arquivo para preencher uma `table` dos itens registrados\escolhidos.

Esse é meu código de autocomplete.

```
$(function() {

    $("#itemsearch").autocomplete({
      source: "/menus/autocomplete_search/",

      select: function (event, ui)
       {
       AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
       {
            ui.item.value = "";
        }

        },
        minLength: 1,

    });
});

var result = 0
var price = 0

  function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
  {
    var selectedObj = ui.item;
    var name = selectedObj.value
    var codigo = selectedObj.item_num
    price = selectedObj.item_price
    var table = document.getElementById('tableItemVenda');
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    row.innerHTML = "<td>"+codigo+"</td> <td>"+name+"</td> <td>R$ "+price+"</td>";
    inserirTotal(price);

}
```

Comment: O que significa escolhido? Select na página? Submit de um form? Isso vai determinar qual evento você vai chamar e a hora que vc chama o backend pra gravar a seleção

Comment: @LeonardoPessoa o item selecionado é o 'ui.item' do autocomplete.  Funciona assim, ao digitar o nome ou o codigo, o(s) itens aparecem na lista suspensa do autocomplete, para escolher o item, o usuario navega com as setas e aperta enter no item que desejar.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui captar as escolhas do usuario chamando a nova funcao 'SaveInvoice' assim que um novo item é selecionado. Sempre que um item é selecionado, é salvo na variável selectedObj.

```js
$(function() {

    $("#itemsearch").autocomplete({
      source: "/menus/autocomplete_search/",

      select: function (event, ui)

       {
       AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
       {
            ui.item.value = "";
            SaveInvoice(); //chama funcao para salvar item para o json
        }

        },
        minLength: 1,

    });
  });

function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)

  {
    selectedObj = ui.item;
}


function SaveInvoice(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/menus/gerar_conta/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {selectedObj, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        });
    }
```